# Why my vuetify form validator is not checking if fields are valid?

Tags: validation, vuejs3, vuetify.js

Before i go to the problem, it is worth mentioning - i am running Vue3 and Vuetify 3.

The problem is with the `this.$refs.form.validate()` function, where the passed in check doesn't check if the form is valid or not. This is making me very anxious at this stage.

My form is pretty much simple:

```
<template>
    <v-form ref="patientDetailsForm" @submit.prevent>
        <v-row>
            <v-col
                cols="12"
                md="2"
            >
                <v-select
                    :items="nameTitles"
                    v-model="formFields.title"
                    label="Title"
                    :rules="[requiredValidator]"
                />
            </v-col>
            <v-col
                cols="12"
                md="4"
            >
                <v-text-field
                    v-model="formFields.first_name"
                    label="First Name"
                    placeholder="First Name"
                    :rules="[requiredValidator]"
                />
            </v-col>
            // there are similar fields, not included here
        </v-row>
        // there are similar fields, not included here
        <v-row>
            <v-col cols="8">
                <v-btn
                    @click="submitForm"
                    variant="elevated"
                    color="primary"
                    block
                >
                    Create A New Patient
                </v-btn>
            </v-col>
            // Other action buttons not relevant
        </v-row>
    </v-form>
</template>
```

And here is my `<script>` which is very very basic as you can see:

```
<script lang="ts">
import {defineComponent} from "vue";
import { emailValidator, requiredValidator } from '@validators'

export default defineComponent({
    data() {
        return {
            nameTitles: [
                'Mr.',
                'Mrs.',
            ],
            formFields: {
                first_name: null,
                title: null,
                // Other fields commented..
            },
        }
    },
    emits: ['sendNewPatientForm'],
    methods: {
        emailValidator,
        requiredValidator,
        submitForm() {
            this.$refs.patientDetailsForm.validate((valid: boolean) => {
                console.log('[FORM] Form validation result:', valid);
                // This is where the problem is! I can't get to "valid" var
                if (valid) {
                    console.log('[FORM] submitForm');
                    this.$emit('sendNewPatientForm', this.formFields);
                }
            });
        },
    },
});
</script>
```

The problem is with the line `this.$refs.patientDetailsForm.validate((valid: boolean) => {`. The `valid` is not passing anything, and i can't access the `valid` part, no logs are returned.

My `@validators` are just various `const export ...` constants wrapped in one `.ts` file. That is not the problem.

I have tried to wrap it in `this.$nextTick()`. But that didn't solve the issue. Next i have tried to create an empty `rules: {}` object and reference it before `this.$nextTick()` so `this.$refs.form.validate()` would have fresh rules to check against - nothing, same quetness from `this.$refs.form.validate()`.

Also i have printed a log to console, where `this.$refs.patientDetailsForm.validate()` is indeed working and printing the results (first invalid form, then valid form):

[image: a console log output]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VForm's `validate()` [does not accept any arguments](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/blob/next/packages/vuetify/src/composables/form.ts#L84), passing a callback does nothing. Instead, it returns a promise that you can await:

```
methods: {
  async submitForm() {
    const {valid, errors} = await this.$refs.patientDetailsForm.validate()
    if (valid) {
     ...
```

---

Consider using VForm's [`@submit`](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-form/#events-submit) event, it works with programmatic submits too, and it receives the promise as input argument, so you can do without the template ref:

```html
<v-form @submit.prevent="submitForm">
```

and

```
methods: {
  async submitForm(submitEventPromise) {
    const {valid, errors} = await submitEventPromise
    if (valid) {
     ...
```

Comment: Very welcome you are, monsieur!